# GUI freezes when executing def function. Use threads?

Tags: python, pygtk, glade

I've made a small program which has 2 buttons and each does certain thing. Here's a simplified version of the code.

Thing is it works fine except that the button freezes and stays in a clicked position and whole GUI freezes until the command is completed.
As far as I know threads would be best to use in this situation, but I have no idea how to implement it in this example.

I use glade and pygtk for gui.

```
    def do1:
        t = 2
        #do something
        time.sleep(t)
        #do something
        time.sleep(t)
def do2:
        t = 3
        #do something
        time.sleep(t)
        #do something
        time.sleep(t)

class we:
        wTree = None
        def __init__( self ):                
                self.wTree = gtk.glade.XML( "ui.glade" )

                dic = {
                        "on_buttonSone" : self.sone,
                        "on_buttonStwo" : self.stwo,
                }
                self.wTree.signal_autoconnect( dic )              
                gtk.main()

        def sone(self, widget):
                i = 0
                while i < 3:
                        t = 1
                        #do something
                        i += 1
                        time.sleep(t)           
                self.wTree.get_widget("entryResult").set_text("Done.")
        def stwo(self, widget):
                start = time.clock()
                array = ['A','B']
                adict = {'A':do1,'B':do2}
                for f in array:
                        adict[f]()
                end = time.clock()
                elapsed = end - start
                gg = round(elapsed,2)             
                self.wTree.get_widget("entryResult").set_text(str(gg))             

go=we()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[pyGTK has a whole section of there FAQ devoted to threading](http://faq.pygtk.org/index.py?req=all#20.1).

20.6 seems like a good minimal example.